# Template for average value from const array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I have following template in c++ for compute average value:

```
template <typename T>
T average(T t[], int n)
{
    T s = t[n - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); i++)
        s += t[i];
    return s / n;
}
```

But when I try call function with constant array I have an error, for example:

```
const double array[5] = { 23.4, 523.5, 55.2, 543.2, 6.4 };
double a = average(array,5);
```

> error C3892: 's': you cannot assign to a variable that is const

How to define this template to compute from constant array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, your function takes a pointer, not an array. `T t[]` in a parameter list is the same as `T* t` for historical reasons.

Just make it take a pointer to const instead of one to non-const:

```
template <typename T>
T average(T const* t, int n) {
    T s = t[n - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); i++)
        s += t[i];
    return s / n;
}
```

Or, even better, take an iterator pair so you can use it with any container and not just C-style arrays:

```
template <typename It>
auto average(It begin, It end) {
    assert(begin != end);
    auto s = std::accumulate(begin, end, 0.0);
    return s / std::distance(begin, end);
}

const double array[] = { 23.4, 523.5, 55.2, 543.2, 6.4 };
double a = average(std::begin(array), std::end(array));
```

Comment: Also, 0.0? srsly? It's `typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use type traits the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T average(T t[], int n)
{
    typename std::remove_const<T>::type  s = t[n - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); i++)
        s += t[i];
    return s / n;
}

int main()
{
    const double array[5] = { 23.4, 523.5, 55.2, 543.2, 6.4 };
    double a = average(array,5);
}
```

Though your function looks strange. Take into account that in general case parameter `n` can be equal to zero. In this case your function will be invalid.